# Вывод элементов в строку ( C++ )

Tags: c++

```
 1. #include <iostream> using namespace std; int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
        double minus = 0;
        double minusnumber;
        double a, b, result = 0;
        char math;
        cout << "Введите выражение: " << endl;
        cin >> a >> math >> b;
        switch (math)
        {
        case '+':
        {
            result = a + b;
            break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
            result = a - b;
            break;
            if (minusnumber > minus) {
                result = minus += minusnumber;
            }
        }
        case '/':
        {
            if (b == 0) {
                cout << "На ноль делить запрещено!";
                break;
            }
            else {
                result = a / b;
                break;
            }
        }
        case '*':
        {
            result = a * b;
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "Не верное значение.";
        }
        cout << "Результат: " << result << endl;   }
```

Всем доброго вечера, кто может подсказать как вывести чтобы можно было писать в одну строчку более двух элементов ?
Пример:
Введите выражение: 2 + 2 * 5 = 12....
( По возможности с объяснением для чего это было сделано, заранее спасибо. )
При этом будет ряд запрещенных критерий:

- стандартные контейнеры типа std::vector
- стандартные алгоритмы (например std::copy) из заголовочного файла algorithms
- строки std::string
- работа с динамической памятью в стиле C, то есть функции malloc, calloc, free (используйте операторы new, delete и delete[]).

Comment: Что такое уже сегодня спрашивали, но с другим аккаунтом

Comment: почитайте про создание интерпретаторов, разбор выражений https://algolist.manual.ru/syntax/parsear.php   https://habr.com/ru/post/489534/